# how to make the process of the app doesn't exit until all the coroutines finish their work without blocking their parent threads in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Consider the following situation:-

Assume that we need to do heavy tasks in a lot of files in our app,

and we create a coroutine for each task,

if we run the app, then the app process will exit before those coroutines finish their work.

someone would suggest to use job.join() for every coroutine,

But this solution will block the parent threads that we created the coroutines in,which will cause problems for me because I'm already executing some other work in these parent threads.

Knowing that if we put those heavy tasks in new threads instead of coroutines then the app process will not exit until all the threads finish their work.

How to make the app process doesn't exit until all the coroutines finish their work, without blocking their parent threads via using job.join()?

In other words how to make the app process wait for the coroutines like how it waits for the threads?

Also I don't want to use async-await because it will also will block the parent thread.

Comment: Kotlin will wait until all coroutines finish by default. They are executing in `CorutineContext` inside context `Dispatcher` holds thread or threads corutine use for execution

Comment: @Evgeny ,sorry Evgeny but this is not true, please try this code in your IDE :- fun main(){ GlobalScope.launch{delay(5000L); println("finished the coroutine")}}. and see if the println() line will execute or not. You will find that the app process will exit before reaching the println() line. But thanks for your effort to help.